# Map where each date holds an array, implementation problem

Tags: javascript, dictionary, collections

I would need a structure where each key (Date) holds an array of integers.
I have tried the following but it does not seem to be working.
I create a record with the array and then set all its values to 0, although it still seems they are NaN:

The first statement creates a record as a Date with an associated array of a length defined by a variable.

```
Dictionary.set(Meteor.jira.formatDate(moment(date),[arrayLenght]);

//initialize the array with 0 values
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arrayLenght; i++) { 
    Dictionary.set(Meteor.jira.formatDate(moment(date))[i]=0);
}

}
```

Comment: Your code has invalid syntax (brackets in first line, closing bracket in last line). Is `arrayLength` a number? Then `[arrayLength]` would create array with one element (that number). Is `Dictionary` a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

Comment: @barbsan  Yes, arrayLenght is a number and Dictioanary is a Map.

Comment: I checked the syntax and it is actually right, it compiles.

Comment: Dictionary.set`(`Meteor.jira.formatDate **(moment *(date)* ,[arrayLenght])** ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill array first, then put it into dictionary.

You can update it's value changing any variable that contains reference to your array.

```js
let Dictionary = new Map();
let arrayLenght = 6;
let key = "2018-11-15" //Meteor.jira.formatDate(moment(date))

let arr = Array(arrayLenght).fill(0);

Dictionary.set(key, arr);

let value = Dictionary.get(key);

console.log(JSON.stringify(value));

value[2] = 1;

value.unshift(33);
arr.unshift(15);

console.log(JSON.stringify(Dictionary.get(key)))
```

Comment: thanks, and what if I want to update one integer in the array under a specific key?

Comment: I've added additional info about updating values in your array.